# Only adding 4 tags, complaining about more than 5?

Tags: bug, tags, editing

This validation error seems wrong. I tried to add a 5th tag only, not more than 5.

> Please enter no more than 5 tags.

I tried both the mobile site and the desktop site in a mobile browser, same result.

[image: Screenshot showing the error message on mobile]

Answer (score 6):

It’s the underscore that’s causing the problem. It doesn’t seem count as a valid “word separator” for tags so “Conrad” and “Stargard” are counting as two different tags. You can see this even more clearly if you press space after the tag and it converts the underscore to a hyphen.

In fact even if this wasn’t standard behaviour I would suggest you always use hyphens instead of underscores in tags so it keeps everything consistent across the site. Actually looking a bit further the [tagging guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18879/345161) on main meta even state you should use hyphens in place of spaces.

> Replaces spaces with dashes (-) to combine multiple words into a single word (i.e, Tag "`Unit Testing`" as "`unit-testing`").

FWIW I can't find an explicit post about the changing of underscores to hyphens in tag names, only [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106032/345161) about improving that feature but it should be enough to prove this is what happens.

Comment: I don't have any problem with using hyphens or underscores, but regardless the error message seems wrong & totally confusing / misleading. Thanks for the explanation of why its happening.

Comment: @DaveInCaz Oh sure it's an imperfect error message _but_ the system does appear to see it as two tags, the visual representation just shows one whilst you are typing it.